# Normalising matrix which contains lists

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, keras, normalization

Currently, I have the following dataframe (the first 30 columns are from `dput()`):

```
structure(list(PacketTime = c(0.0636830000000002, 0.0691829999999989, 
0.0639040000000008, 0.0636270000000003, 0.0656370000000024, 0.064778000000004, 
0.0616950000000003, 0.0666280000000015, 0.0630829999999989, 0.0665130000000005, 
0.0621160000000032, 0.0654010000000014, 0.0652889999999928, 0.0640989999999988, 
0.0621339999999861, 0.0645319999999998, 0.065757000000005, 0.0624459999999942, 
0.061782000000008, 0.0626439999999917, 0.0648419999999987, 0.0664910000000134, 
0.0644649999999984, 0.0654030000000034, 0.0657139999999998, 0.0642799999999966, 
0.069137000000012, 0.0631520000000023, 0.0634139999999945, 0.0615009999999927
), FrameLen = list(c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), 
    c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L
    ), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 
    276L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L, 
    276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 
    276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 
    276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 
    276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 
    276L, 276L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 
    276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L, 276L, 
    276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 
    276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L), c(304L, 276L, 276L)), IPLen = list(
    c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L
    ), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 
    272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L, 272L, 272L
    ), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L, 272L, 272L), 
    c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L
    ), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 
    272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L
    ), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 
    272L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L
    ), c(300L, 272L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L, 272L, 272L
    ), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 
    272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L), c(300L, 272L, 272L)), Movement = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

From here, I can use the `keras` package to put the dataframe (in variable `packets`) into a matrix using:

`packets.m <- as.matrix(packets)`

However, when I attempt to pass this into the model (without normalisation) or normalise before passing, I receive the following error:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     Matrix type cannot be converted to python (only integer, numeric, complex, logical, and character matrixes can be converted

Thus, how can I effectively normalise the two columns `FrameLen` and `IPLen` containing lists, so that I can accurately use this for the deep learning model using the `keras` package?

**EDIT:** The full `dput()` can be found here, for the packets dataframe https://pastebin.com/cXKdSB2y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you trained this data

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## Multiple instances

```
df %>% 
  unnest()
```

## Multiple features

```
df %>% 
  mutate(position = map(FrameLen,seq_along),id = row_number()) %>%
  unnest() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = position,values_from = c(FrameLen,IPLen))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "depends on how you trained this data"? This data in the frame is just processed from raw traffic analysis dumps off Wireshark. The aim is to get it ready for splitting into training/testing sets for modelling

Comment: Adding onto this, I see what you're meaning. The list values for FrameLen and IPLen count together as a single feature of the one instance.

Comment: Yeah I don't think keras can train on lists, at least not on R and I am not even sure that this is possible on theory, but then again I rarely play with Deep Learning, when I use it I always have to force the data to be off the same size

Comment: On using the multiple features solution you get with my dataframe, I get the warnings: `Values in `FrameLen` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(FrameLen = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(FrameLen = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(FrameLen = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates`. Some of the columns in the output have `c(x, y, ...)` instead of being properly split into the respective columns.

Comment: I have edited the OP to include the full `dput()` so you can see for yourself what I mean

Comment: I caught the problem you have rows with identical data, an id will solve that, fixed the answer, please upvote and approve if this worked out

Comment: I am now getting the error, `Error: Column "id" is of unsupported type function`. I'm assuming this is from the addition of `id = row_number`. Is this meant to be `id=row_number()`?

Comment: it shouldn't matter if you use row_number or row_number()

Comment: Apparently using `row_number()` fixed the issue.